# NotifyIcon click event fires later than form deactivate

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I set the form invisible when deactivated, and NotifyIcon click event as visibilty switch. If I click the NotifyIcon when form is visible, the form will hide and then quickly show up, for NotifyIcon click event fired later than form deactived event. How can I deal with this?

---

Problem code:

```
private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Visible)
    {
        Visible = true;
    }
}

private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Visible = false;
}
```

---

Now I'm using a timer to prevent the quickly change, but it's ugly:

```
private readonly Timer _timer = new Timer(200);
private bool _canChangeVisible = true;
```

In constructor:

```
_timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
{
    _canChangeVisible = true;
    _timer.Stop();
};
```

Event handler:

```
private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Visible)
    {
        _canChangeVisible = false;
        _timer.Start();
        Visible = false;
    }
}

private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_canChangeVisible && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Visible = !Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I can't answer by telling you how but i can tell you that you cannot do it by hiding the form in the deactivate event. It will always fire before any other events you will want to trigger in the same program.

Comment: @Franck I want action like the volumn controller in windows 10, when you click outside it hides. I tried use a global mouse hook, but I failed to figure out whether the tray icon is clicked.

Comment: @W.Leto how about canceling the click of the notifyicon if the form deactivated event had fired up a couple milliseconds earlier.

Comment: @Franck That is what I did in my below code, not working everytime.

Comment: @W.Leto did you try my answer ?

Comment: @Franck Yes, thanks for your answer, but I think it is generally the same as I have done, while I wanna know if there is a better solution.

Comment: @W.Leto there is quite a big difference between yours and mine. Yours your form don't always hide and if it shows back from the click on the icon you lost the focus and cannot hide by clicking on the desktop again unless you go manually click the form again then the desktop. You might want to look at the event order [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms) and you will see by yourself there is no other solution as deactivate is the last and only event you can do this. Unless you change language you might have other options

Comment: @Franck My original code messed, but it works, because I hooked the global mouse event by which I controll part of hiding logic. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what i was implying in my comment.

In the `form` you should have a the following. What it does is logging the time when the last deactivate occured. If the person click too fast while deactivate we want to skip it because it's already closing down which is what you are trying to do.

```
public DateTime LastDeactivate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    LastDeactivate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

In the application context i don't know your full code but here's my full working version

```
public class MainContext : ApplicationContext
{
    private NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    private Form1 form = null;

    public MainContext()
    {           
        notifyIcon.Text = "test";
        // whatever the icon
        notifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.Folder;
        notifyIcon.Click += NotifyIcon_Click;

        // make the icon visible
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;
    }

    private void NotifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // special case for the first click
        if (form == null)
        {
            form = new Form1();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            // test if the form has been recently closed. Here i consider 1/10
            // of a second as "recently" closed. So we want only to handle the click
            // if the time is greater than that.
            if ((DateTime.Now - form.LastDeactivate).TotalMilliseconds >= 100)
            {
                // specially control the show hide as visibility on/off
                // does not trigger the activate event that screw up the
                // later hiding of the form
                if (form.Visible)
                {
                    form.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    form.Show();
                    form.Activate();
                }
            }
        }
    }      
}
```